# prove $\frac{e^{iuX_t}} {\mathrm{E}{[e^{iuX_t}]}}$ is martingale

Tags: stochastic-calculus

...knowing that $X_t$ has independent increments and is adapted to its natural filtration, $u \in \mathrm{R}$

My problem is in particular how to show this process has finite mean...(can I use the fact that $e^{iux}$ is bounded $\forall x\in\mathrm{R}$?)

EDIT $E[e^{iuX_t}]\neq 0$

Comment: Hint: for u sufficiently close to zero, the expectation in the denominator is bounded below and for all u, the expression in the numerator is bounded by $1$ in modulus.  Notice also that it is possible that there exist u for which the expectation in the denominator is zero.

Comment: "Notice also that it is possible that there exist u for which the expectation in the denominator is zero."

how is this possible, since the exponential never reaches zero...?
can you provide me an example to better understand?

Comment: Take a uniform random variable on the interval $[0,2\pi]$ or on the discrete set $\{0, \pi\}$ and set $u = 1$ for some simple examples.  The exponential can have cancellations which sum to zero.

Comment: What remains of the question since the result does not hold in general? Supplementary hypothesis or deletion?

Comment: sorry for being so late, adding the condition that $E[e^{iuX_t}]\neq 0$ is sufficient (other than necessary) to show that this process is a martingale?
using increments I arrive till
$\frac {e^{iuX_s} E[e^{iu(X_t-X_s)}]}{E[e^{iuX_t}]}$

I'm not sure if I am allowed to simplify to arrive to $\frac{e^{iuX_s}}{E[e^{iuX_s}]}$.

ps I added the extra-condition to the original post